# Why doesn't Deuteronomy 13:6-10 list that the is father liable to get the death penalty for committing the act of apostasy?

Tags: children-parenting, parashat-reeh, apostasy

Why doesn't Deuteronomy 13:6-10 list that the is father liable to get the death penalty for committing the act of apostasy?

"If thy brother, the son of thy mother, or thy son, or thy daughter, or the wife of thy bosom, or thy friend, which [is] as thine own soul, entice thee secretly, saying, Let us go and serve other gods, which thou hast not known, thou, nor thy fathers; [Namely], of the gods of the people which [are] round about you, nigh unto thee, or far off from thee, from the [one] end of the earth even unto the [other] end of the earth; Thou shalt not consent unto him, nor hearken unto him; neither shall thine eye pity him, neither shalt thou spare, neither shalt thou conceal him: But thou shalt surely kill him; thine hand shall be first upon him to put him to death, and afterwards the hand of all the people. And thou shalt stone him with stones, that he die; because he hath sought to thrust thee away from the LORD thy God, which brought thee out of the land of Egypt, from the house of bondage." (Deut.13:6–10)

Comment: These are people who are connected by affection. A father is an authority figure not an affection figure so as to seduce one.

Comment: Mom's not in there, either.

Answer (score 1):

Rashi says on [R'ei 13:7](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9977#v=7&showrashi=true) explains

> *[Or your friend,] who is as your own soul:* This refers to your father.
>   Scripture enumerates those [persons] who are dear to you; how much
>   more so [must you apply this] to others [and not spare them]!

The pasuk does not refer to the father directly but refers to him indirectly since the father is normally an referred to in terms of fear and respect rather than closeness.

Rav Hirsch says that

> The Torah lays stress on the most intimate relationships, the ties of
>   blood, of marriage, and of friendship - shows just therebye what value
>   and what justification it recognizes on their influence on the
>   feelings and trend of thoughts - and want to protect loyalty to the
>   Torah against any attack by those most justifiable and most powerful
>   bonds.

Thus, the relationship by blood is most intense through the mother. Therefore, the father is not required in the pasuk as any lesser bond than the mother would of course be required to be rejected if the person attempts to seduce one into idolatry.

Note that neither parent is referred to directly because the fact that they are the generation above showd that there is a matter of respect involved which is somewhat more remote than the immediate affections of children of the same mother.